# Calculating the minutes between dates

Tags: sql-server

I need help converting the following excel logic below to SQL subquery. Your help is very much appreciated.

Column C

- Row 2) 10/1/12 4:24 PM
- Row 3) 10/1/12 4:25 PM
- Row 4) 10/1/12 4:26 PM
- Row 5) 10/1/12 7:27 PM

Accumulated Minutes

- Row 2) 2
- Row 3) 1
- Row 4) 1
- Row 5) 45

Excel Formula

- Row 2) =IF((C3-C2)>45,45,(C3-C2)*1440)
- Row 3) =IF((C4-C3)>45,45,(C4-C3)*1440)
- Row 4) =IF((C5-C4)>45,45,(C5-C4)*1440)
- Row 5) =IF((C6-C5)>45,45,(C6-C5)*1440)

Comment: What have you tried?  What is in row 1?  What do the Excel formulas have to do with your problem?

Comment: Do you want to know about DateDiff or how to do running total queries or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH CTE(RowNumber, Date) AS(
select 1, '2012-01-10 16:22' union
select 2, '2012-01-10 16:24' union
select 3, '2012-01-10 16:25' union
select 4, '2012-01-10 16:26' union
select 5, '2012-01-10 19:27'
)
select b.Date, IIF(DATEDIFF(minute, a.Date, b.Date) > 45, 45, DATEDIFF(minute, a.Date, b.Date)) as AccumulatedMinutes
from CTE b left outer join CTE a on a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
```

It returns:

```
2012-01-10 16:22    NULL
2012-01-10 16:24    2
2012-01-10 16:25    1
2012-01-10 16:26    1
2012-01-10 19:27    45
```

Comment: Thanks, Chrisb. How do you prevent the expression from calculating NULL values? I tried the following but failed. Any ideas? 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL(b.Date,a.Date), ISNULL(b.Date,a.Date)) > 45
  THEN 45 ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL(a.Date,b.Date), ISNULL(b.Date,a.Date)) END )as 'AccumulatedMinutes'

Comment: wrapping the IIF() with ISNULL will give you 0 instead - ISNULL(IIF(...), 0)